# How to build an openwrt image with gargoyle instead of Luci?

Tags: openwrt, gargoyle

First of all, I'm new to this OpenWrt, and all custom build firmwares.
How to compile the OpenWrt source with the Gargoyle or X-wrt UI instead of Luci?
I couldn't find anything in the documentation to show how to do that, and I know it's doable because of [this](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/faq/about).
In my first compilation I fallowed this steps [buildroot.exigence](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/buildroot.exigence).